# How to create a surrogate key column in existing table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I would like to create a new column called `PurchaseOrderID` in an existing table using SSMS. It combines `LineNumber` and `PONUMBER` to create a surrogate key and then I would enter into table *design* mode and assign it a PK there.

Creating new column:

```
ALTER TABLE FactPurchaseOrders
ADD PurchaseOrderID VARCHAR(64);
```

Populating with values:

```
UPDATE FactPurchaseOrders
SET PurchaseOrderID = (CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), LineNumber) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), PONUMBER))
WHERE 1=1;
```

Currently with this I am unable to assign this column a PK and I believe because it is nullable.
I have also tried creating it in design mode first and the same problem occurs.

[image: Error when trying to save PK]

Comment: Hopefully I'm not missing something, but after you updated the column value, did you check the `Allow Nulls` checkbox in the table designer and save the definition prior to adding the PK constraint?

Comment: Also as a point of validation, you can run `SELECT PurchaseOrderID, COUNT(*) FROM FactPurchaseOrders GROUP BY PurchaseOrderID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to ensure there are no duplicate rows which would also prevent a PK constraint from getting created.

Comment: Why are you creating that column at all? creating what is effectively a calculated column is a really bad idea. Just make the PK over both columns. If that's not possible for some reason (like a very deficient front end that only supports single column PKs) then make it a calculated column. As it is, you're trying to violate basic database design principles and you're heading for a world of pain as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is most certainly the case.  After you have run your update, simply alter the columns you will use in your PK to NOT NULL.  Since the columns will have values now it can be set as NOT NULL and then it will allow the assignment of PK.  Also make sure there isn't already another PK on the table already.  There can be only 1!

1. Update Records
2. Alter columns to not null
3. Create PK on fields

Comment: [This message](https://gyazo.com/c0800e1b79dd15208bf822ecc84fbd6f) pops up after I assigned a PK and tried to save.

Comment: @JonathanPorter fyi: As a rule, links to external images are frowned upon. If the image vanishes then the value of SO is diminished. If the image contains text then you may be expecting people to enter the text by hand, e.g. sample data for database questions. For an error message it makes more sense to simply quote the message in your post or comment.

Comment: @JonathanPorter try doing it through SQL.  ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ColumnName VARCHAR(XX) NOT NULL instead of using the GUI.

Comment: Just an amendment to @Matt A.'s response - to remove that warning, to go `Tools > Options > Designers >Table and Database Designers` and Uncheck the *Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation* checkbox.  May have to restart SSMS for it to take effect.

Comment: @bassrek While that works, and in a lot of cases it would be fine, Microsoft themselves do not recommend this and provide a workaround.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956176.  Just thought I would round out that answer (I actually didn't know about the checkbox, but checked your response)

Comment: Thanks @Matt A.  I never actually put too much thought into the wording of the option and didn't realize it was a bug; I just assumed it was calling T-SQL in the background.  It's odd that this bug has persisted for so long.

Comment: In addition to @Matt A.'s answer, I was getting the error: "_Saving changes is not permitted. The changes you have made require the following tables to be dropped and re-created._" The way I got around this was to use: `ALTER TABLE FactPurchaseOrders ADD PRIMARY KEY (PurchaseOrderID)` instead of trying to add the PK through the GUI. Thank you everyone for your help!